# Running multiple applications on the same Azure WebRole (Cloud Services)

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I currently have an Azure cloud service with a web role (so it's a virtual machine with IIS installed on it). This web role currently runs an unique web application (WebAPI project).

What I'm trying to do is to create a new web application, but I need it to run on the same web role (i.e. two applications on the same virtual machine) to reduce the costs. I know it's possible (both web application will then run on the same IIS instance, on the same machine, with different ports) but I can't find resources about how to do it with a recent version of the Azure SDK.

I found great resources :

- [Multiple site strategy on web role(s) and cloud service(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464912/multiple-site-strategy-on-web-roles-and-cloud-services)
- https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/
- http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/
- http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/11/azure-running-multiple-web-sites-in-a-single-webrole/

but all are a bit old (<= 2013) and don't apply anymore.

I'm currently using the Azure SDK 2.6. I've tried modifying my ccproj file (Cloud Service project file) so both WebAPI project share the same `RoleName`:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject1.csproj">
  <Name>Website</Name>
  <Project>{...}</Project>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
  <RoleName>MyRole</RoleName>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject2.csproj">
  <Name>Website</Name>
  <Project>{...}</Project>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
  <RoleName>MyRole</RoleName>
</ProjectReference>
```

This doesn't work, the "roles" node of my project within Visual Studio shows an error (`"no project associated [project 2 name]`).

I've also tried to modify my `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file:

```
<WebRole name="xxxx.Frontend.Azure" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
        <Site name="Web">
            <Bindings>
                <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
            </Bindings>
        </Site>
        <Site name="AnotherWeb" physicalDirectory="foo">
            <Bindings>
                <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
            </Bindings>
        </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
        <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8080" />
        <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="http" port="8090" />
    </Endpoints>
</WebRole>
```

No luck either.

How should I proceed?

---

EDIT :

Here's my current csdef file with modification for multiple sites support:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureCloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="XXX.YYY" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
  <WebRole name="XXX.ZZZ" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="ZZZ" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\XXX.ZZZ\azure.publish">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8081" />
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="http" port="8090" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with the csdef file changes, and the wrong track with the ccproj changes. So get rid of your second ProjectReference, since you just want one WebRole at the end of the day.

What you *should* do in the ccproj file is add a line like this:

```
<MSBuild Projects="..\MyProject2\MyProject2.csproj" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="PublishToFileSystem" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PublishDestination=..\Publish\MyProject2\;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False" />
```

Obviously that has fake paths, but what's important is that you make sure the path to the csproj file is valid, and make sure that the PublishDestination path matches the PhysicalDirectory path you're specifying for that Site in the csdef file, and note that the PhysicalDirectory path and the PublishDestination path are **not** relative to the same location. For example, we keep a "Publish" directory in the solution root, so for us the PublishDestination looks like

```
..\Publish\MyProject2\
```

and the physicalDirectory looks like

```
..\..\..\Publish\MyProject2
```

Your endpoint configurations look correct, but if a role isn't accessible remotely, make sure that your csdef file has a line in Endpoints:

```
    <Endpoints>
        <InputEndpoint name="MyProject1Endpoint" protocol="http" port="80" />
        <InputEndpoint name="MyProject2Endpoint" protocol="http" port="8080" />
    </Endpoints>
```

...with a "name" that corresponds to the endpointName of each Site:

```
    <Sites>
        <Site name="MyProject1Site" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\MyProject1">
            <Bindings>
                <Binding name="MyProject1Binding" endpointName="MyProject1Endpoint" />
            </Bindings>
        </Site>
        <Site name="MyProject2Site" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\Publish\MyProject2">
            <Bindings>
                <Binding name="MyProject2Binding" endpointName="MyProject2Endpoint" />
            </Bindings>
        </Site>
    </Sites>
```

That's assuming you want each site publicly accessible on the same port it's hosted on. If, for some reason, MyProject2 were running locally on port 8081, you'd add `localPort="8081"` to that InputEndpoint.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track (I think). I still have to fix some issues, but it sounds really promising

Comment: Well I successfully deployed my two applications on the same web role. Unfortunately, only one of them is available through Internet (I'm getting a timeout when trying to reach the other). I've remotely connected to the VM (using RDP),I can see both applications are correctly deployed/running, and both are even accessible locally. So I'm assuming there is some network configuration issue for the one application that doesn't respond when reached through Internet. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: A role that's accessible locally but not remotely sounds like it must be an Endpoint configuration issue. Your Endpoint configuration in your original question looks correct, but I added some example config lines to my answer nevertheless. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I've double-check my bindings, I don't see any issue with them. I've edited the question with the current version I have

Comment: Your config looks much like our (working) example, so I'm not sure what else I can add. Some superstitious stuff that might help: I prefer to keep binding/endpoint names unambiguous—"Endpoint1Binding" and "Endpoint1Endpoint", rather than calling both "Endpoint1". I'd also try deploying the cloud service with just the single, 2-site WebRole ("XXX.ZZZ" in your csdef).

Comment: Finally found the issue: a simple typo when trying to reach out the web application...
So all of this works fine. The exact modifications I made to the ccproj are the ones explained here: https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/
Thanks again

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm getting again the issue with another deployment of the same cloud service: one application is available, the other isn't. I double checked the port I used for the binding, no typo this time. I'll investigate, but something might be causing trouble after all

Comment: @SeanMahan this works great although I did need to change anything in any project file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can deploy the app as an Azure Web App instead, I would highly recommend it. It is designed to handle this scenario really well. You can create an App Service Plan with however many server instances you need and then multiple apps share that group of servers.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't easily change the way the application is built, so I have to stick with Cloud Services. I'm sure there is a solution though (as a web role is a simple Virtual Machine with IIS in it)